# False Dependency in Gerrit after a git pull

Tags: git, gerrit

I did the following in Git, and now have a false dependency issue.

1. Created a new branch, using `git checkout -b fixPlayer`
2. I made some changes to the code, and created some new files too, then staged for commit using `git add -A`
3. I then committed the changes via `git commit`
4. I then created a new branch a couple days later, using `git checkout -b fixLaserAim`
5. (**Where the chaos started, I think**). I thought that my local working copy of "master" might be out of date, so while in this branch, I ran `git pull`. I think this caused some sort of merge issue. So I switch back to master, update it (`git checkout master`, `git pull`), then switch back to my second branch, `git checkout -b fixLaserAim`.
6. I finish my changes for fixLaserAim, stage for commit, `git add -A`, and commit it `git commit`.
7. Finally, I switch to my earlier branch, "fixPlayer", and push it, `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`, and then switch over to my "fixLaserAim" branch, and do the same thing.

Both of these changes appear in Gerrit, but for some reason, "fixLaserAim" notes that it is dependent on "fixPlayer". The two do not touch any of the same files, and I'm trying to find out how to remove this dependency in Gerrit, because it is blocking automated builds and the change eventually going into production.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: why do you want to remove the dependency? every commit is dependening on the previous commit - this is normal. when you abandon a commit, then dependent commits have to be pushed again.

Comment: [How to get rid of false dependecies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402285/how-to-get-rid-of-false-dependencies-in-gerrit)

Comment: I had found this question already, but it doesn't help, as I did indeed create a new branch for each patch.

Comment: do you have change-IDs in the commit msg? maybe you made the second branch wrongly: `git checkout -b fixLaserAim` created from `fixPlayer` where the commit has been made already (3rd step). have you tried creating new branch from master? `git checkout -b fixLaserAim origin/master`

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367147/git-remote-merge-commit-causing-false-dependencies-in-gerrit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was a server side bug in Git itself. Resolved.